# Unable to populate grid onclick event in Asp.net Web Forms Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, telerik

I'm attempting to populate a grid AND create / download an Excel file from the OnClick event of a button.  The create / download works as expected, but I am unable to populate the grid - unless I comment out the code for creating / downloading the Excel file.  If I do that it works just fine, the grid is populated as expected.  How can I get both to work with the OnClick event of the same button?  I'm using VS2019, WebForms.

Here is the aspx code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 form-group">            
        <em>Begin Date and Time: </em>
        <telerik:RadDateTimePicker ID="rdtpBeginDate" runat="server" Skin="Default" Width="100%">
            <Calendar runat="server">
                <SpecialDays>
                    <telerik:RadCalendarDay Repeatable="Today" ItemStyle-BackColor="#3399ff"></telerik:RadCalendarDay>
                </SpecialDays>
            </Calendar>
        </telerik:RadDateTimePicker>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 form-group">
        <em>End Date and Time: </em>
        <telerik:RadDateTimePicker ID="rdtpEndDate" runat="server" Skin="Default" Width="100%">
            <Calendar runat="server">
                <SpecialDays>
                    <telerik:RadCalendarDay Repeatable="Today" ItemStyle-BackColor="#3399ff"></telerik:RadCalendarDay>
                </SpecialDays>
            </Calendar>
        </telerik:RadDateTimePicker>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 form-group">
        <asp:Button Text="Export" OnClick="ExportExcel" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-sm btn-primary" /> 
    </div>
</div>

<hr />

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 form-group">
        <asp:Label ID="lblScores" runat="server"></asp:Label>

        <telerik:RadGrid 
            runat="server" 
            ID="rgScores" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <MasterTableView>
                <Columns>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Department" ReadOnly="True" HeaderText="Department" SortExpression="Department" UniqueName="Department" FilterControlAltText="Filter Department column" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="True"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="AuditCount" HeaderText="AuditCount" SortExpression="AuditCount" UniqueName="AuditCount" FilterControlAltText="Filter AuditCount column" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="True"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="AverageScore" HeaderText="AverageScore" SortExpression="AverageScore" UniqueName="AverageScore" FilterControlAltText="Filter AverageScore column" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="True"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                </Columns>
            </MasterTableView>
        </telerik:RadGrid>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the aspx.cs for the OnClick event:

```
protected void ExportExcel(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //The following populates a grid
        SqlDataSource sdsScores = new SqlDataSource();
        sdsScores.ID = "sdsScores";
        this.Page.Controls.Add(sdsScores);
        sdsScores.DataSourceMode = SqlDataSourceMode.DataSet;
        sdsScores.ConnectionString = constr;
        sdsScores.SelectCommand = "SELECT Department, count(id) AS AuditCount, AVG(FinalScore) AS AverageScore, CASE WHEN AVG(FinalScore) > 87 THEN 'Outstanding' WHEN AVG(FinalScore) > 72 AND AVG(FinalScore) <= 87 THEN 'Exceeds Expectations' WHEN AVG(FinalScore) > 58 AND AVG(FinalScore) <= 72 THEN 'Meets Expectations' WHEN AVG(FinalScore) >= 44 AND AVG(FinalScore) <= 58 THEN 'Needs Improvement' ELSE 'Below Expectations' END AS ScoreCategory FROM PhaudDeptsConf WHERE AuditDate Between @ScoresBeginDt and @ScoresEndDt GROUP BY Department";
        sdsScores.SelectParameters.Clear();
        sdsScores.SelectParameters.Add("ScoresBeginDt", rdtpBeginDate.DbSelectedDate.ToString());
        sdsScores.SelectParameters.Add("ScoresEndDt", rdtpEndDate.DbSelectedDate.ToString());

        rgScores.DataSource = sdsScores;
        rgScores.DataBind();

        lblScores.Text = "Interdepartmental Comparison";

        //The following creates and downloads an Excel file
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM PhaudDeptsConf WHERE Department = @Dept AND AuditDate BETWEEN @BeginDt AND @EndDt"))
            {
                //cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Dept", deptString);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BeginDt", rdtpBeginDate.DbSelectedDate);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndDt", rdtpEndDate.DbSelectedDate);

                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                    {
                        sda.Fill(dt);
                        using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
                        {
                            wb.Worksheets.Add(dt, "Phauds");

                            Response.Clear();
                            Response.Buffer = true;
                            Response.Charset = "";
                            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
                            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=SqlExport.xlsx");
                            using (MemoryStream MyMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                            {
                                wb.SaveAs(MyMemoryStream);
                                MyMemoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
                                Response.Flush();
                                Response.End();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm using Telerik for the grid, but I'm getting the same issue when I use GridView as well.

Comment: I think the problem is that you're streaming a file back to the browser with your MemoryStream - Response code; even though you've bound a grid to some data before this, the browser isn't going to render this. I'm guessing when the above code runs the file downloads, and the page stays exactly the same ?

Comment: @sh1rts - you are correct.

Comment: That should tell you all you need to know. When you call `Response.End();` after buffering the file contents in the response, you are ending the page's ability to do anything else afterwards (at least in terms of rendering).

Answer (score 0):

You will also need a data adaptor and a data set for you GridView.

try:

```
sdsScores.Open();
SqlDataAdaptor dataAdaptor = new SqlDataAdaptor(query,connectionString);

DataSet myData = new DataSet();
sdsScores.Fill(myData, [tablename]);

GridView.DataSource = myData;
GridView.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `rgScores.DataBind();` as telerik radgrid auto binds the data in onNeed_DataSource Method. Problem can be because of this.